# Objective-C - Using NSScanner to read string?

Tags: objective-c, nsscanner

SO I am trying to read content of an html string.

```
[scanner scanUpToString:@"<" intoString:&result];
```

What is the fastest way to read the content into string but ignore the last character which in this case is "`<`". I don't want to do `stringByReplacingOccuranceOfString`, that would perform slow

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NSScanner's

`-scanUpToString:(NSString *)stopString intoString:(NSString *)result`

does not include the stopString in the result; you don't need to ignore the last character, because it's not included.

Comment: oo my bad, I meant remove the first character, because I am scanning from "<" to ">", so the problem is having a "<" at the beginning of the string

Comment: @aryaxt Put a `[scanner scanString:@"<" intoString:nil]` before scanning the content to skip it. `@Scott` You're missing an asterisk on the `result` parameter: `(NSString **)result`;